# React Native state and props, callbacks problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having problems with passing props and this whole stuff. Apparently i did something wrong maybe someone can tell me what should i fix there.

So these are states and callbacks that i use:

```
const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
  const visibleCallBack = () => {
    setIsVisible(false);
  };
  const [budynekText, setBudynekText] = useState("budynek");
  const budynekCallBack = (propFromChild) => {
    setBudynekText(propFromChild);
  };
```

isVisible should decide whether to render or not a certain component:

```
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setIsVisible(true)}>
      <View style={styles.budynekContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.budynekTekst}>{budynekText}</Text>
        {isVisible ? 
          <Rozwijana callBack={visibleCallBack} budCallBack={budynekCallBack}/>
         : null}
      </View>
```

Here I'm passing these callback functions as a props to "Rozwijana",
"Rozwijana" looks like that:

```
export const Rozwijana = ({callBackProp, budCallBackProp}) => {
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.rozwijanaPoz}>
      <Pusty/>
      <Box name={"budynek 1"} callBackProp={callBackProp} budCallBackProp={budCallBackProp}/>
      <Box name={"budynek 2"} callBackProp={callBackProp} budCallBackProp={budCallBackProp}/>
      <Box name={"budynek 3"} callBackProp={callBackProp} budCallBackProp={budCallBackProp}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Then i pass these callbacks down to "Box" component:

```
const Box = ({name, callBackProp, budCallBackProp}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {callBackProp(); budCallBackProp(name);}}>
        <View style={styles.inputBox}>
          <Text style={styles.testText}>{name}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </>
  );
}
```

The result is, that when i click first time at "budynek" button it works as expected, it opens my "list" but after that, when i try to click any of "Boxes" nothing happens. Is there something wrong? If so, how do i go about making this work? Thanks

Comment: `const [isVisible, setIsVisible]` is this destructuring? if it is then it will be `const {isVisible, setIsVisible}`

Comment: It's a React Native hook "useState" it returns a pair in which first item is a state variable and second one is function used to update it.

Comment: @EnginnerS.Saad yes, it's array destructuring, you are trying to do an object destructuring.

                        @Snowenik I dont understand what the problem is, you want to conditionally render something and it's appearing, but looking at your code i don't see a case where you are able to show something, as you are just putting a value to `isVisible` to `false`

Comment: "Rozwijana" should render itself only if state variable "isVisible" is true. Generally what i want to do, is to render this element "Rozwijana" once this TouchableOpacity is pressed and then, hide this component/unrender it so to speak once some touchable meaning my "Box" component is pressed. "budCallBackProp" is additional callback for passing data. I am passing these callbacks down App -> Rozwijana -> Box. Yes i am initializng "isVisible" to false, so it will not render unless, user touches some TouchableOpacity, which on its onPress, sets "isVisible" to true.

Comment: But it seems, like for some reason that my Boxes are not getting these callBacks.